# column "birthdate" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

Tags: postgresql, insert-select

This query throws an error: column "birthdate" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

```
INSERT INTO profile.profile(name,gender,birthDate,userId)
      SELECT 
          userId,
          substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 5) AS name,
          substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 2) AS gender,
          to_timestamp('2021-08-09 13:57:40', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AS birthDate
      FROM 
          generate_series(1,10) AS y(userId)
```

My table:

```
      CREATE TABLE profile.profile 
        (
          id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
          name character varying NOT NULL, 
          gender character varying NOT NULL, 
          birthDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
          image character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT 
            'https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/274/947/png-clipart-computer-icons-user-business-believer-business-service-people.png',
          userId integer NOT NULL, 
          CONSTRAINT UQ_profile_user UNIQUE (userId), 
          CONSTRAINT PK_profile PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your insert statement is trying to insert the gender into the birth_date column. The order/data is wrong for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the order of the columns in the `INSERT` so that it corresponds to the order of the values to be inserted :

```
INSERT INTO profile.profile(userId,name,gender,birthDate)
```